# PHP restriction to pages

Tags: php, validation, cookies

I'm having a problem with a web site I'm creating so I want to know:

How can I prevent that an unauthenticated user could acces the website by doing something like:

Website.com/content

It suppose that unauthenticated user cannot acces the page content, but if they write it directly in the address bar they can see the content. So how can I prevent this to happen? How can make to only allow authenticated users see the content when they write it in the address bar?

I want to do this using cookies... by the way I already implemented the authentication using the database.

Comment: Well, check the cookie and authorization on the `website.com/content` page before outputting it.

Comment: Could you be more specific. What does `Website.com/content` contains? Is it another PHP script, or a content file such as an image?

Answer (score 0):

place a check

```
<?
if (!authorized()) { # substitite with your own authorize function
    header('401 Unauthorized', 401);
    die('You are not authorized!');
}
?>
```

on the page.

**UPDATE:** place it before you start output. If you are not using `ob_start`, that means at the top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a  page for error message "website.com/unauthorize"

and a inlcude file, "check_auth.php", while user logged in, validate user and pass and create a cookie "userLogin" with value 0 or 1. 
1 to represent successful login, 0 for invalid id/pass.

and include check_auth.php in every file in which you want restrictions.

```
include "check_auth.php";
```

and in this file write:

```
<?php 
if ( ! isset($_COOKIE['userLogin']) && $_COOKIE['userLogin'] != 1 )
{
    header("Location: website.com/unauthorize");
}
```

this will check for login state and will redirect unauthorize users to error page. include this file in all the pages on top where you require restriction.

Answer (score -1):

I'm normally an asp.net developer. And in asp.net we have a master page, It's like a template you can put other content pages into.

If PHP have something similar (include?) Then you could make a function that checks if a user is supposed to be where he is, and if not redirect him to the login page. And include that on all the not-accessible pages.